# Twilio - timeout attribute for voice: <DIAL>

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have a landline that I want to forward calls to.

If I call that landline (without using twilio), it will ring 20+ times before giving up.

In twilio, I have a very simple call forward twiml bin that looks like this:

```
<Response>
<Dial>
+1-415-123-2345
</Dial>
</Response>
```

... and when I dial my twilio number, the call forwards, but only rings 6-7 times before giving up.  This is unexpected since the default value of the timeout attribute is 30 seconds.

If I explicitly set the timeout attribute, like this:

```
<Response>
<Dial timeout="30">
+1-415-123-2345
</Dial>
</Response>
```

... the behavior is unchanged - the call still gives up after 6-7 rings.

How can I set my twilio call forward to ring longer than 6-7 rings before giving up ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simply setting the timeout to 90 instead of 30.

The actual number of seconds in the timeout value doesn't necessarily correspond to what you think of in "time I spend listening to rings" so if it isn't long enough, just increase it ...